# How put a mask in str column pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I'm try do the formatation below in a pandas dataframe

```
In [7]: doc_number = '37545841000194.0'
In [8]: doc_formated = '{}.{}.{}/{}-{}'.format(doc_number[:2], 
doc_number[2:5],doc_number[5:8],doc_number[8:12], doc_number[12:14])
      ...: print(doc_formated)
37.545.841/0001-94
```

dataframe

```
df["CNPJ"]
'37545841000194.0'
'30882452000105.0'
'90385616000110.0'
'55366990000178.0'
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```py
df["CNPJ"].map(lambda p: '{}.{}.{}/{}-{}'.format(p[:2], 
p[2:5],p[5:8],p[8:12],p[12:14]))
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Dont work, i get this erro "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" @Muhteva

Comment: This is a type of error that you get when you try to call ```str``` like a function. Are you sure that this snippet of code causes that error? Is there a possibility that some other part of the code is the reason of the error?